# How can I install GEOS?

Tags: matplotlib, installation, matplotlib-basemap

I have problems installing basemap.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-db2649dcf0a1> in <module>
  2 import numpy as np
  3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in <module>
154 # create dictionary that maps epsg codes to Basemap kwargs.
155 pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']
--> 156 epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))
157 epsg_dict={}
158 for line in epsgf:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/andreamathis/opt/anaconda3/share/proj/epsg'
```

It looks that a the file 'epsg' is missing. Has somebody encountered this error before and knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: If possible, try starting your python installation over with anaconda. It handles dependencies for you.

Comment: @farenorth thanks. I am interested in installing basemap, I am not sure if I can do that with anaconda...

Comment: It is true that basemap is being replaced by cartopy, and so I recommend switching to that if possible. If not, it looks to me like basemap is still available in Anaconda ([here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/basemap)). In the past I've been able to install basemap directly (on OSX) following the instructions you mention in the Q, but it's been a while (since I now use Anaconda). Long story short: use Anaconda.

Comment: hi @farenorth, thanks for your post. I have installed basemap from anaconda but I still have problems running the code above...

Comment: If you can find a file `epsg` on your system, say `/usr/x/y/epsg`, then `export PROJ_LIB=/usr/x/y` before the import.  (On Unix / Macos, `cd /; find -name epsg`).